# при 2 клике не выделяется весь метод, а только слово в этом методе android studio

Tags: android-studio

Что то натыкал в настройках студии.
И теперь при 2 клике не выделяется весь метод, а только слово в этом методе.
Такая же история при клике на переменной например при 2 клике на переменной charLen выделяет только char или Len.

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить?

android studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

фух нашел, в Setting>Editor>Generel галочка Honor doubleclck.